# Sharing GIF file from Storage programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio

Alright, this is my first post ever so I'm sorry if I'm missing something on my post.

I'm developing an app for Android and one of the main features is sharing GIF files from the device's storage.
I've already successfully coded the "download" part, so the file is "detected" when sharing but there's a small issue: The GIF appears static when sharing to WhatsApp, and I was wondering if maybe one of you beautiful fellow coders could help me out in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code for shareFile:

```
private fun shareFile() {
        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/LGP/yellow")
        val fileURI = Uri.parse(file.absolutePath.toString() + ".gif")

        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "image/gif"
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Partilhar Este Gesto"))
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is a very big project and this is a very crucial part of the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are doing wrong will be clear if you start that intent. You will get a very special exception which you do not catch so your app crashes. After that you can find the exception in the logcat. Please tell which it was.